# How to determine the number of layers your CNN has?

Tags: conv-neural-network

How to determine the number layers you have in a CNN.  For example, in the code snippet given below, how can you determine the number of layers in the CNN?

**CODE**

```
# Construct model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(num_rows, num_columns, num_channels), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean how to count them per hand or a tensorflow function that returns the amount of layers? If second is the case, this should be it:

`layer_amount = len(model.layers)`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Together with this solution, how do you count them per hand or per section...i.e. for example, how many layers are in `model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(num_rows, num_columns, num_channels), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))`...and so on?

Comment: hm, so the definition of layers is not very clear I think. Because you could count them like blocks (so one block would be conv+maxpool+dropout) or you could count them like conv is one layer, maxpool is one, dropout probably wont count as layer. What number does ```len(model.layers)``` give you? And btw. you shouldnt use dropout with convolution layer, use batchnorm instead. Dropout is mainly for dense layers

Comment: Thanks!  `len(model.layers)` gives me 14.  Does that mean that I have 14 layers?

Comment: yes! So it seems that keras counts everything you add with ```model.add(...)``` as a layer, you can count it by hand and you'll see that its 14 indeed :)